# como convertir este argumento a un entero python

Tags: python-3.x

estoy creando una pequeña función con el modulo sys, la cuestión es que el ultimo numero de los argumentos siempre es un numero que la itera otra funcion y para acceder a ese argumento uso la indexacion de esta manera (sys.argv[-1]).

```
import sys

def funcion():
    numero = int(sys.argv[-1])
    for n in range(numeros):
         otra_funcion()
```

Sin embargo al convertir el numero de "str" a "int" me muestra el siguiente error

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:`

Alguien sabe una manera de convertir el ultimo argumento de la lista de argumentos para poder iterar. Perdón por la pregunta sin mucho sentido pero soy un programador novato y no tengo mucha experiencia con python, Gracias por su atención.

Comment: Te sugiero colocar cual es tu valor de entrada.

Comment: No debería haber ningún problema si lo corres en la consola con: `python archivo.py parametro1 parametro2 4`, aunque de igual forma en el `for` cambia la variable `numeros` por `numero` o te saltara otro error. Si por el contrario lo corres directamente con un vscode o pycharm con el botón de run desconozco si puedes agregar parámetros manualmente pero esa podría ser la causa por la que no te detecta ningún parametro.

Comment: @Jhoubert Rincon valor de entrada?, te refieres al primer valor es un argumento str

Comment: Sí, me refiero a cuales son los argumentos que le estas pasando.

Comment: el paso de los argumentos seria ejemplo       leer mostrar 5                                                    por lo cual lee y muestra 5 veces

Comment: bueno básicamente lo que necesito es que el ultimo numero de los argvs sea un int para iterar con un for

Comment: Estoy 100 por ciento seguro que el último argumento no se puede castear, es otro tipo de objeto. No necesariamente debe de ser el tercer argumento, el indice -1 se refiere al último argumento. ://

Comment: @gcoronel99 bueno entonces existe otra manera de acceder al ultimo numero de la lista, y convertirlo a int, ahora que me acabo de dar cuenta que esta iterando argumento por argumento y necesito iterar la longitud de los argvs.

Answer (score 0):

Dado a que no conozco tu valor de entrada para el ultimo argumento, te sugiero atrapar la excepción y ver tu valor de entrada:

```
import sys

def funcion():
    try:
        numeros = int(sys.argv[-1])
    except ValueError:
        print(sys.argv[-1], "No es un entero")
        # 0 Evitará entrar al for (puedes usar return para salir del método)
        numeros = 0 
    for n in range(numeros):
         otra_funcion()
```

Esto te ayudará a saber si tu valor esta siendo tomado correctamente,

Sí tu parámetro tiene decimales te recomiendo usar float.

```
numero = int(float(sys.argv[-1]))
```

Espero te sea útil.

Answer (score 0):

Te cito un fragmento de la referencia del atributo `sys.argv` en la [documentación de Python 3.8.x](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html):

> The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script. argv[0] is the script name (it is operating system dependent whether this is a full pathname or not).

Entonces, se refiere a una lista que contiene todos los argumentos con los que se **ejecuta el script**:

```
python.py sys.argv[1] sys.argv[2] ...
```

En este ejemplo se empieza la lista por el indice 1, ya que según dice el anterior fragmento `argv[0]` es el nombre/ubicación del script.

Ahora, veamos un ejemplo práctico:

```
import sys

def main():
    print(f"Mi nombre es {sys.argv[1]} y tengo {sys.argv[2]} años")

main()
```

Al ejecutarse **se debe de usar argumentos**:

```
persona.py Gabriel 14
```

Da como resultado:

```
Mi nombre es Gabriel y tengo 14 años
```

De lo contrario terminaría en error:

```
File "C:\Users\gabriel\Desktop\persona.py", line 4, in main
    print(f"Mi nombre es {sys.argv[1]} y tengo {sys.argv[2]} años")
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Si se adaptase esta linea de código de esta manera

```
print(f"Mi nombre es {sys.argv[1]} y tengo {sys.argv[-1]} años")
```

No importa cuantos argumentos se pasen ya que el indice -1 se refiere al **último elemento de la lista**. La demostración:

```
persona.py Gabriel no no argumento ... 14
```

Se pasarón 6 argumentos, y solo tomó en cuanta el primero y el último:

```
Mi nombre es Gabriel y tengo 14 años
```

**Ahora, respondiendo a tu error:**

```
numero = int(sys.argv[-1])
```

Esa linea asigna el valor de un casting a la variable `numero`. Un casting consiste en validar el literal de un elemento como el tipo de casting. Cito lo que dice la [referencia en la documentación oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

> Return an integer object constructed from a number or string x, or return 0 if no arguments are given. If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string

Aclarando, `int()` realiza un casting. Este convierte el string que recibe como parámetro en un literal numérico. Si el literal pasado en string **no es válido**. Va dar un error:

```
print(int("Soy inválido"))

  File "C:\Users\gabriel\Desktop\ejemplo.py", line 1, in <module>
    print(int("Soy inválido"))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Soy inválido'
```

**Pero, ya vayamos a como solucionarlo:**

Hay que tener en cuenta que le estamos haciendo el casting a entero al último argumento. Entonces el error se produce por que este argumento no es un número.

```
import sys

def funcion():
    numero = int(sys.argv[-1])
    print(numero)

funcion()
```

Si ejecutamos el script así

```
persona.py 6
```

va a dar este resultado

```
6
```

Si embargo, si se ejecuta así

```
persona.py hola
```

terminará en error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hola'
```

**Otras observaciones**

Te recuerdo que `sys.argv[0]` es el nombre del script, y sys.argv[-1] es el último argumento. No importa cuantos argumentos hayan, el indice -1 se refiera al último.

```
for n in range(numeros):
```

Esa linea itera sobre un rango de una variable que no existe, supongo que te refierías a números. Si es así te dejo una manera de cumplir lo que querías (si es que entendí bien):

**El Script:**

```
import sys

def otra_funcion():
    print("Estamos activos")

def funcion():
    numero = int(sys.argv[-1])
    for n in range(numero):
        otra_funcion()

funcion()
```

**La ejecución:**

```
ejemplo.py bla bla bla 5


Estamos activos
Estamos activos
Estamos activos
Estamos activos
Estamos activos
```

**Enlaces que te pueden servir:**

- [Conversión de tipos (casting)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversi%C3%B3n_de_tipos)
- [Proceso de análisis léxico en Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html)

Espero te haya servido.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, pero al ejecutarla me da error  `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'E:\\Trabajos\\Scripts\\Argumentos\\test.py' `